# Calculation & derivation of de-Broglie wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

How to calculate the de Broglie wavelength of an $\alpha$ particle that is accelerated through a potential difference of $V$ from rest.

Comment: With the convenient search function, you can find similar questions including answers like this one: [link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/calculating-de-broglie-wavelength)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" problems.

Comment: When you google "de Broglie wavelength energy", the second hit is http://www.chemteam.info/Electrons/deBroglie-Equation.html . This tells you exactly how to do it. As @TheDarkSide said - the policies of this site discourage "do my homework for me" questions, and ask that you focus on principles and concepts in questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A=qU

  Based on work-energy theorem:
  [image]
- A=(mv^2)/2
- (mv^2)/2 = qU
- mv^2=2qU

> ***mv***=(2qU)/v

and then you can find the de Broglie wavelength by :

[image]